# Using element.click() recursively causes memory problems and slows down/crashes the browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, babeljs, react-dom

I am new to react and decided to make a minesweeper game to learn by doing. I have run into some trouble when it comes to clearing the tiles recursively if they are not touching any bombs.

I decided to handle a click event for every `square` component that makes up the `board`. This click handler first checks if a bomb is clicked, then checks if the square is already clicked or flagged, and if it is not, it clears the square. If the square is not touching any bombs, it should also clear its adjacent tiles. I want to clear these adjacent tiles by calling element.click() on them, but as I have learned, calling element.click() so many times slows down the browser and takes up a lot of memory.

I am asking:

1. Is there another way to invoke a click on an element that does not cause this problem? (problem = lots of memory usage and broken browser)
2. Is there a way I could call the click event handler for a component that has already been rendered? (as to avoid the element.click() call)
3. Is there something wrong in my code that causes these problems that is not an issue with element.click()?

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/door-bell/pen/WKNJyy

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleRightClick = this.handleRightClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      status: 'unclicked',
      touching: this.props.touching,
      isBomb : this.props.bomb
    };
  }
  handleClick(isBomb) {
    if (isBomb) {
        document.writeln('game over!');
        return;
    }
    if (this.state.status !== 'clicked' && this.state.status !== 'flagged') {
        this.setState({status: 'clicked'});
        if (this.state.touching === 0) {
            var adjacentSquares = getAdjacentSquares(this.props.row, this.props.col);
            for (var i = 0; i < adjacentSquares.length; i++) {
                var element = document.querySelector('[row="'+adjacentSquares[i].row+'"][col="'+adjacentSquares[i].col+'"]');
                if (element && element.classList.contains('unclicked')) {
                    console.log('clicking...'+JSON.stringify(adjacentSquares[i]));
                    element.click();
                    console.log('clicked one');
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
  handleRightClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    switch (this.state.status) {
      case 'unclicked':
        this.setState({status: 'flagged'});
        break;
      case 'flagged':
        this.setState({status: 'unclicked'});
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  render() {
    var states = {
        'unclicked': ' ',
        'clicked': this.state.touching,
        'flagged': '*'
    }
    return (
      <td 
        row={this.props.row}
        col={this.props.col}
        className={'tile ' + this.state.status}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.state.isBomb)}
        onContextMenu={this.handleRightClick}>
      {states[this.state.status]}
      </td>
    );
  }
}
```

The getAdjacentSquares method that returns an array of objects {row: x, col: y}

```
function getAdjacentSquares(row,col) {
    var adjacentSquares = [
        {
            row: row+1,
            col: col+1
        },
        {
            row: row,
            col: col+1
        },
        {
            row: row+1,
            col: col
        },
            {
            row: row-1,
            col: col-1
        },
        {
            row: row,
            col: col-1
        },
        {
            row: row-1,
            col: col
        },
        {
            row: row+1,
            col: col-1
        },
        {
            row: row-1,
            col: col+1
        }
  ];
  return adjacentSquares;
}
```

Comment: I guess you call `click()` on them too early, at a point where the originally clicked square isn't cleared yet. So each click tries to clear the entire field, which triggers new clicks, etc. The proper way is to clear the field using a painters algorithm, without calling `click()` again.

Comment: can I see the `getAdjacentSquares()` method?  an edit if you will, I cannot open codepen from work.

Comment: @ChrisG what do you mean "too early" with calling click()? should I do something else first? And after googling painter's algorithm, I have trouble seeing how that could be implemented here, could you please clarify? Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: @NappingRabbit edited, thanks!

Comment: @doorbell `this.setState()` isn't synchronous; when you call `this.setState({status: 'clicked'});`, the Square is marked as clicked at some point in the future, not right away. Which means square A clicks B, then B clicks A, then A clicks B again, and so on. Times 8, ad infinitum.

Comment: I should add: this code works great for one or two adjacent "zero" squares, but when there are many zero squares touching (i.e., 1 bomb on a 10x8 grid) the memory usage shoots up.

Comment: @doorbell I agree about painter's algorithm I dont see the relevance.  Here I see a problem with the disconnect from the time you set the state to `clicked` and the time the tile is placed that has a class `clicked`.  For this reason the recursive function is redundant.  I can imagine a couple `hacky` ways around it, involving conditional logic to compare the `element` with the object, or [changing] the class properties at the same time you `setState()`...  both compromise your design pattern though.

Comment: @ChrisG since I'm calling click() before the state is even set to unclicked, maybe I should put the code that calls click() into the callback for setState()?

Comment: @doorbell Yes, that could solve it. The painter's algorithm is indeed completely irrelevant; I was confusing it with the bucket-fill algorithm.

Comment: My most recent comment did the trick, thanks for your help Chris and NappingRabbit!